# loop an object and removing based on condition in react

Tags: reactjs

I am using reactjs have the following data below and I want to loop through the array and remove the two entry.

```
0: {mailId: 'one@gmail.com', firstName: 'one'}
1: {mailId: 'two@gmail.com', firstName: 'two'}
2: {mailId: 'three@gmail.com', firstName: 'three'}
3: {mailId: 'four@gmail.com', firstName: 'four'}
4: {mailId: 'five@gmail.com', firstName: 'five'}
```

The below two email I want to check it against array and needs to remove it.

```
three@gmail.com
five@gmail.com
```

I'm expecting a final array like below

```
0: {mailId: 'one@gmail.com', firstName: 'one'}
1: {mailId: 'two@gmail.com', firstName: 'two'}
2: {mailId: 'four@gmail.com', firstName: 'four'}
```

If the mail id is only one we can remove like below, but if mailId is again list/array then how can we remove it,  please help me.

```
arrayfilter.filter((item) => item.mailId !== "three@gmail.com")
```

Comment: Use [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes): `array.filter(i => removeThese.includes(i.mailId))`

Comment: thank you, let me try

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.filter and .includes to filter array with array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47785624/filter-and-includes-to-filter-array-with-array)

Answer (score 1):

Use filter and check if your blacklist emails are includes the `mailId`

```js
const arr = [{mailId: 'one@gmail.com', firstName: 'one'},
 {mailId: 'two@gmail.com', firstName: 'two'},
 {mailId: 'three@gmail.com', firstName: 'three'},
 {mailId: 'four@gmail.com', firstName: 'four'},
 {mailId: 'five@gmail.com', firstName: 'five'},]
 
 const blackList = ["three@gmail.com", "five@gmail.com"]
 
 
 const result = arr.filter(item => !blackList.includes(item.mailId))
 
 console.log(result)
```

Comment: let me check it

Answer (score 1):

```js
const data = [
{mailId: 'one@gmail.com', firstName: 'one'},
{mailId: 'two@gmail.com', firstName: 'two'},
{mailId: 'three@gmail.com', firstName: 'three'},
{mailId: 'four@gmail.com', firstName: 'four'},
{mailId: 'five@gmail.com', firstName: 'five'},
]

let newArray = [];
const remove = ['three@gmail.com', 'five@gmail.com']

data.forEach(ele => {
  if(!remove.includes(ele.mailId)) {
    newArray.push(ele)
  }
})

console.log(newArray)
```

Comment: let me check it

Answer (score 0):

```
arrayfilter.filter((item) => !["three@gmail.com", "five@gmail.com"].includes(item.mailId))
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.